# Accessing links with docker compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I have a an angular app that communicate with express server. I have linked the angular app to the express server. I could ping the link inside the angular container but shows error when used in the code.

**Docker Compose file**

```
myexpress: 
    build: express-server 
    links:
      - "mymongodb:mongo"
    ports:
      - "8080:3000" 
  angular: 
    build: angular 
    links:
      - "myexpress:express"
    ports:
      - "4200:4200"
```

I can access the application at http://localhost:4200/. The code fragment of the http call is:

```
return this.http.post('http://express:3000/signup', body, {headers: headers})
      .map((response: Response) => response.json())
      .catch((error: Response) => Observable.throw(error.json()));
```

The console shows the following error:
[image]

How to access the link from the angular container?

Comment: try http://myexpress and delete the links block.

Comment: Its still the same with the modification. I used `ping express` and I'm getting output for that. It has to be something else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The communication among containers takes place through their hostname. By default service name is considered the hostname, so you should use `http://myexpress:3000` to connect to `myexpress`.

Also, you can specify hostname separately. More details [here](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#domainname-hostname-ipc-mac_address-privileged-read_only-shm_size-stdin_open-tty-user-working_dir).

Comment: I get error even after changing request as `http://myexpress:3000/signup `. The errors says : `net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED`

Comment: Use hostname and that would drive away all the confusion

Comment: I have solved the issue by making the angular and express into a single container.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing the **container_name** option inside the compose file.

```
myexpress: 
    build: express-server 
    container_name: myexpress
    links:
      - "mymongodb:mongo"
    ports:
      - "8080:3000" 
angular: 
    build: angular 
    links:
        - "myexpress:express"
    ports:
        - "4200:4200"
```

Comment: I have tried this but it doesn't solve the error. I have some other container linked in the same way. So it must be something else.

Answer (score 0):

This is old but I was working with something similar and I realized that my browser is running in the host not in any service's container.

Then the host does't have access to the express domain because the domain is living in the docker network not in the host network

I created a configuration for nginx to handle this, I hope this can help someone:

```
// default environment
export const environment = {
    production: false,
    apiUrl: 'http://localhost:3000' // this is for development purpose
};

// prod environment
// used when build is created for the docker image
export const environment = {
    production: true,
    apiUrl: '' // empty string: for the api redirection @fallback conf
};

// angular service
urlBase = `${environment.apiUrl}/apiEndpoint`;
findById(id){
  let headers = new HttpHeaders( { 'Content-Type': 'application/json'});
  let request = this.http.get( `${this.urlBase}/${id}`, {headers: headers});
  return request.toPromise();
}

//nginx.conf
server {
  listen 80;
  location / {
    #serve angular built
    root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index index.html index.htm;
    #try files, if a path fails in angular then the fallback is used
    try_files $uri $uri/index.html @fallback;
  }
  #fallback for express redirect
  location @fallback{
    #set the backend fallback, this will send requests to express container
    #in the frontend baseUrl should be empty
    proxy_pass http://express:3000; #set the backend service domain here
  }
}
```

Also, both services should belong to the same network, and you have to mount the nginx config into your web container

```
version: "3"
networks:
  mean:
services:
  web:
    build: client
    image: mean-frontend
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    depends_on:
      - express
    networks: 
      - mean
    volumes:
      - ./nginx/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
    restart: always
  express:
    build: server
    image: mean-backend
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    depends_on:
      - mongo
    environment:
      WAIT_HOSTS: mongo:27017
    networks: 
      - mean
  mongo:
    image: mongo
    restart: always
    volumes: 
      - ./dbData:/data/db
    networks: 
      - mean
```

Finally, the browser will call the angular app, when a path in angular is not valid the fallback will redirect the call to the express service using the docker network